# Unable to set googlemaps to user active location swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I followed some of the docs online [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#location) to set up google maps API and I am able to load it into the view. I do have one problem - when I get the user's location, the view of the google map won't show/snap/animate to user's location. I am able to get the user's location successfully.

My Location Manager:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let newUserLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = newUserLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = newUserLocation.coordinate.longitude
    userLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude)


    let Camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude, zoom: 15)
    self.MapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.MapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero , camera: Camera)

}
```

My Viewdidload:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, not sure if this is effective but, it works for me in my ios simulator. I ended up adding these two lines of code after creating the Camera variable:

```
    MapView.animate(toLocation: newUserLocation.coordinate)
    MapView.animate(toZoom: 15)
```